# GCM Server ( The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.)

Tags: android, asp.net, .net, wcf, google-cloud-messaging

I have been working over GCM Server in .net but I am unable to post data to server and always getting this error .

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

The asp.net code is mentioned below.

```
        string regId = "xxxx1bER6XXjuEhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf_thTnR7CSxxxxxxqX60-jxxxN55xxxxK074AaV9M09jP2xxxxu28aXXrd6ltxxxxxxhvmVt-nxxfw";


          var applicationID = "AIzaxxxxxt6fJx5txxxxxx";



            var SENDER_ID = "x8xxxxxx030x";
            var value = Text1.Text;
            WebRequest tRequest;
            tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            tRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            tRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

             //Data_Post Format
             // string postData = "{'collapse_key' : 'demo', 'registration_id': [ '" + regId + "' ], 
              //'data': {'message': '" + Label1.Text + "'},'time_to_live' : '3' }";


            string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
                + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";


            Console.WriteLine(postData);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

            Label3.Text = sResponseFromServer; //printing response from GCM server.
            tReader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
```

I have entered right credentials but still the error exists . I am stuck with this scenario for two days now , please help me regarding GCM Server in .NET WCF . Thanks

Comment: have you added the required APIs?

Comment: I am just calling GCM Server by this way . No API I have added . can you guide me which API are you talking about please?

Comment: I have tested the following command and it is throwing Unauthorized error all the time   # api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

# curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"   I am not sure what is going on when I have valid API key.

Comment: I guess for GCM to be used you have to add GCM.jar file into your libs folder. There is a process about all this, check this link http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: gcm.jar is added in Android project , it is not for .NET Server. I am trying to curl but it is also throwing same exception as you can see above.

Comment: Please post your log, also try to put your server side curl code, and where do you get the exception

Comment: curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSxxxxxatisdQ44rEM353xxxxxx29mBVsxxxx" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"aXaxax\"]}"

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>  This is the error I am getting .

Comment: is your device registered over GCM? where you sending this message through your .Net service?

Comment: Yes my device is registered and I got the Registration ID from my App as well but I am stuck at server side still :(

Comment: just to make sure, your ID for registered device came from GCM is what you have in your regId variable right?

Comment: And the API key you are using is of what? API or for WEB? try to change them, I mean use WEB if using API or vice versa to see the difference, mostly it occurs because of it, as I also had similar problems

Comment: Saqib , I have tried all the API Key ( Browser Key , Server Key , Android Key ) But none of them working . I have done that 3 months ago in different projects but now nothing is working , only unAuthorized error is been sent back all the time I am trying to access the URL with Authroized Key .

Comment: Then try to restrict the access by providing your valid server IP address by just letting your server access the devices. It may work that way, try ot

Comment: I have allowed all the ips to test and it is working now , that seems like ip locking was not correct . Thanks

Comment: @Mani how you allow all ip's for test please elaborate this sentense. i stuck same problem like you.

Answer (score 0):

Open firebase console then import Google project in firbase and click on setting and download "google-services.json" use server key as api key then run android app and genrate registration id and then send notification it will be work